# How to reclaim unused space from lvm volume group to create new physical partition

Tags: linux, lvm

I would like to reclaim some space from my lvm2 volume group to create a new physical partition to install a second OS for dual boots. I am afraid I may have painted myself into a corner with the disk configuration I made, as documented below.

As you can see, I have more than 200GB unused space in my volume group.

I have something like the following in mind in the order shown:

5. shrink physical volume /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt by ~200 GB
6. shrink cryptsetup partition by ~200GB
7. shrink physical partition /dev/nvme0n1p3 by ~200 GB
8. create new partition /nvme0n1p4 on the remaining space for the new OS

Any ideas anyone ?

```
lsblk /dev/nvme0n1
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
nvme0n1               259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:2    0   3,7G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:3    0 927,3G  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   253:0    0 927,3G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0 672,8G  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
    │                                            /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0    20G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    
-----

sudo gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB            
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): E530359E-4120-494C-8BD0-601BDA6DE269
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2014 sectors (1007.0 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048         1050623   512.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2         1050624         8885955   3.7 GiB     8300  
   3         8885956      1953525134   927.3 GiB   8300 
   
-----

sudo cryptsetup status /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt is active and is in use.
  type:    LUKS2
  cipher:  aes-xts-plain64
  keysize: 512 bits
  key location: keyring
  device:  /dev/nvme0n1p3
  sector size:  512
  offset:  32768 sectors
  size:    1944606411 sectors
  mode:    read/write
  flags:   discards

------

sudo pvs
  PV                          VG       Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   
  /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt vgubuntu lvm2 a--  <927,26g <234,42g


-----
 
sudo vgs
  VG       #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree   
  vgubuntu   1   2   0 wz--n- <927,26g <234,42g


------

sudo lvs
  LV     VG       Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root   vgubuntu -wi-ao---- <672,84g                                                    
  swap_1 vgubuntu -wi-ao----   20,00g
```

Comment: What is the filesystem of root LV?

Comment: file system of root is ext4

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  I used Ubuntu 22.04 and I installed KDE partition manager which did all I wanted.